# Get Shadow Width of a GdkWindow

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3, gnome, gdk

Is there a way to get the shadow size of a [GdkWindow](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Windows.html)?

When requesting and moving windows using the `GdkWindow` object, I am finding that for Gnome based apps, the functions `get_frame_extents()` and `move_resize()` are including the shadow area as part of the window. I later noticed that `window.move_resize()` works properly if I first call `window.set_shadow_width(0,0,0,0)`. This is not ideal because I don't actually want to set the shadow, I just need to know how large the shadow is.

Comment: You should ask for this on the GNOME bug tracker.

Comment: Thanks, I posted it there: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=766496